# Gulp to generate a file per folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to write a gulp task to build javascript file and concatenate a single file for each folder, including the root folder.

I have found this solution: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md

> If you have a set of folders, and wish to perform a set of tasks on
>   each, for instance...
>
> ```
> /scripts
> /scripts/jquery/*.js
> /scripts/angularjs/*.js
> ```
>
> ...and want to end up with...
>
> ```
> /scripts
> /scripts/jquery.min.js
> /scripts/angularjs.min.js
> ```

However, this only builds `*.js` file for all the subfolders inside `scripts` folder. I'm trying to build the `*.js` file inside the root folder scripts, i.e. my expected output will be:

```
/scripts.min.js
/scripts/jquery.min.js
/scripts/angularjs.min.js
```

I'm new to node so I'm confused now how to achieve that. Really appreciate your help on this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day, I have come up with some sort of modifying as below.

```
var paths = {
    js: {
        folder: 'dev/assets/js'
    }
};

gulp.task('js', function() {
    var folders = getFolders(paths.js.folder);
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
        return gulp.src(path.join(paths.js.folder, folder.path, '/*.js'))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(concat(folder.name + '.min.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js.dest));
    });
    merge(tasks);
    browserSync.reload();
});

var getFolders = function(dir) {
    var folders = [{path:'',name:'app'}];
    var folder = fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
        });
    for (var i=0; i<folder.length;i++) {
        folders.push({path: folder[i], name: folder[i]});
    }
    return folders;
};
```

I have separated the directories and the names for combined script into 2 properties of an object. So I don't need to have different tasks for the root folder and subfolders.

Please feel free to give your comments on my approach :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a separate task (baseScripts) for creating the minified scripts for the base directory.  Then create another task (allScripts) that runs both the baseScripts and subScripts tasks.

```
var scriptsPath = 'src/scripts';

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('allScripts', ['baseScripts', 'subScripts']);

gulp.task('subScripts', function() {
   var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

   var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
      return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/*.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename(folder + '.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));
   });

   return merge(tasks);
});

gulp.task('baseScripts', function(){
  return gulp.src(scriptsPath + '/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I have thought about this but I'm trying to use a single task for all script. You can take a look at my approach below and give me feedback. Thanks :)